# javascript .send() not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mobile, mobile-browser

this javascript is working on desktop but not on mobile browsers. Is there an edit which could resolve this?

The script send the results to a questionnaire to a google document to pull out the results. It works ok on a desktop browser but no luck on mobiles.

```
<script>

var myForm = document.getElementById("questionnaire");
if (myForm) {
  myForm.onsubmit = function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var questionDiv = document.getElementById('question-div');
    var busyDiv = document.getElementById('busy');
    var resultDiv = document.getElementById('result-div');
    var resultList = document.getElementById('result-list');
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url =     "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzGx6a6eogfVTaKD_3a4kiLBZfcdD5GMoonNsSSY1-sCCJfPDI/exec";
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.onload = function() {
      if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        var result = response.result;
        for (var i in result) {
      var e = result[i];
          if (e) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        if (e.url) {
              var a = document.createElement('a');
          a.href = e.url;
              a.textContent = e.name;
          li.appendChild(a);
        } else {
          li.textContent = e.name;
        }
        resultList.appendChild(li);
      }
        }
        busyDiv.hidden = true;
        resultDiv.hidden = false;
      }
    }

    var form = document.getElementById('questionnaire');
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    var fields = ['name','email','yob','gender','income','asset','q1','q2','q3','q4','q5','q6','q7','q8','q9','q10'];
    var params = [];
    for (var i in fields) {
      var field = fields[i];
      params.push(field + "=" + formData.get(field));
    }
    xhr.send(params.join('&'));

    questionDiv.hidden=true;
    busyDiv.hidden=false;


    return false;
  };
}
</script>
```